# Subscript out of range error. How to correctly call out workbook in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I have code the grabs the latest workbook in a folder. I am having issues calling the workbook out properly. I wrote out a portion of the code that im using. I'm mainly having issues with ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("wb.name").AutoFilter.Sort._ the 'wb.name' portion.

I already tried "wb.name" to call out the file and I get a subscript out of range error.

```
' code to grab the latest file
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    'Latest File Code
    Dim MyPath As String
    Dim MyFile As String
    Dim LatestFile As String
    Dim LatestDate As Date
    Dim LMD As Date

    MyPath = "C:\Users\TAmon1\Desktop\Cir Bandwidth Dashboard"
    If Right(MyPath, 1) <> "\" Then MyPath = MyPath & "\"
    MyFile = Dir(MyPath & "*.csv", vbNormal)
    If Len(MyFile) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No files were found...", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Do While Len(MyFile) > 0
        LMD = FileDateTime(MyPath & MyFile)
        If LMD > LatestDate Then
            LatestFile = MyFile
            LatestDate = LMD
        End If
        MyFile = Dir
    Loop

Workbooks.Open MyPath & LatestFile

Dim wbcsv As Workbook, wbplanning As Workbook
Set wbplanning = Workbooks("Planning_tool.xlsm")
Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(MyPath & LatestFile)

'Need to properly call out the latest file
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("wb.name").AutoFilter.Sort._
```

Comment: Did you check if wb is set to a workbook? or if its null

Comment: What are you trying to do here: `ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("wb.name").AutoFilter.Sort._`

Comment: I did a macro that would remove duplicates in a column. I didn't show the rest of the code since it wasn't necessary

Comment: Wb is set to workbooks

Comment: Do you in fact have a sheet in `wb` that is named `"wb.name"`? From your comment of `Need to properly call out the latest file`, it would appear all you want is `wb`, because `wb` already is the latest file. `ActiveWorkbook` at that point is also `wb`, because Open makes the opened workbook active.

Comment: yes its default sheet 1